# Simple PHP class to send email via SendGrid service

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I'm trying out integration of the [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/home/b) transactional email service with PHP scripts on my site. For my purpose all I need it to do is to be able to send a single text-based email from the 'Contact' page on my site. And that is it!

So I found [this PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) which unfortunately has too much "stuff" in it. I'd hate to upload 1.7 MB of PHP code to my server without knowing what's going on there.

So I'm curious, is there a simple PHP implementation, idk, using `sockets` to connect to SendGrid servers to do the following?

1. Send a single plain-text email to a short list of recipients.
2. Get a result: success/failure, etc.

Answer (score 14):

i used PHPmailer and it works like a charm

```
    $mail=new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();    
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;               
    //sendgrid
    $mail->Username="apikey";
    $mail->Password = $api;   //api key from sendgrid
    $mail->Host="smtp.sendgrid.net";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';   
    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->FromName = 'From name';
    $mail->AddAddress($to);  // Add a recipient
    $mail->MsgHTML($sbody);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body    = $sbody;
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
  }

    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll let others vote on whether it works or not. I abandoned SendGrid and went with SendinBlue. (See my own answer.)

Comment: It is not accepting the username and password. It says SMTP: ERROR -> Password not accepted from the server. : 535

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly the answer to my original question, but it is the answer to the question, `"Simple PHP class to send email"`

I spent **over a day** trying to make SendGrid PHP samples work for my server. I might be an old school, but I wasn't using `Composer` for my existing code, and SendGrid examples would not run without it. On top of that, I didn't want to adjust my existing PHP code-base to work with their classes, or go into debugging theirs to extract the working parts. (I had enough headache having been dumped by Mandrill to add more to it.)

I then posted a question on the SendGrid community forum... and received nothing.

I submitted a ticket to their tech support... and received nothing. (To this day.)

So my solution was to keep looking. That's when I found [this review](https://www.ventureharbour.com/transactional-email-service-best-mandrill-vs-sendgrid-vs-mailjet/) of transactional email services, and first tried Amazon SES (which was a big pain in the a%# to set up, so I didn't go with it. Here's a nice [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps0vpgMyJm4) that will show how complicated just a setup is.)

I then tried [SendInBlue](https://www.sendinblue.com/) and totally liked the ease with which it worked. Their PHP class to send transactional emails is [just one](https://apidocs.sendinblue.com/tutorial-sending-transactional-email/) `.php` file, 22 KB in size. No `composer`, none of other dependencies. It worked without giving me any headache. The deliverability was great as well. I was able to set up an account that ran out-of-the-box within 15 minutes (after all necessary verifications and such.) There were some restrictions on how many emails one can send from a new account, but after you contact their tech support (or establish yourself, I guess) they will take some of those out. So my test email was able to reach Hotmail, Outlook, GMail servers without a problem. It got straight into Inbox. I didn't even have to set up SPF and DKIM records. By default emails you sent use SendinBlue signature. Later I set up my own SPF and DKIM records after I contacted their tech support and received a prompt reply with instructions.

So I'm really impressed with SendinBlue for my needs (i.e. small number of transactional emails.) Even their free account seems to work really nice, and then for $8/mo. you can lift some of their sending quotas.

SendinBlue is a French company, so it may not be affected by some of the legal/political BS that's happening in US now. They are also not as big as SendGrid or Mandrill/Mailchimp so they haven't grown a "big head" yet like those two. So, SendinBlue, let's keep it this way!

*Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with any of the services I mentioned above.*

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer works fine also with Sendgrid web service - the example by @bob_1982 is correct. However, there might be issue if you are using version PHP 5.6+. Since this version PHP stream setting `SSL peer verify` changed from default `FALSE` to default `TRUE` and this causes particularly at Sendgrid error `Failed verifying SSL certificate`. Following PHPMailer SMTP stream settings should fix the issue:

```
$phpMailer->SMTPOptions = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
];
```

However, disabling peer verification is definitely not advised due to security and instead of applying such a workarounds the service provider should fix the issue. See also related issue with SwiftMailer - https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have SendGrid PHP helper library:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php
and then you should follow the instructions on the GitHub page.

**EDIT**
Sorry I missed that you brought it up. You don't need to upload 1.7 MB. It's several classes

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that he provided other application, because this app does not need 1.7 MB, it's several files to upload.

Comment: Thank you, both. I don't know if it works or not because I abandoned SendGrid. Their customer service and script samples suck! Read my own answer for details.